# [eslint]'react-redux' should be listed in the project's dependency+unable to resolve path to module 'react-redux'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, eslint

I'm following an Udemy course on react native, and the instructor has just introduced Redux. I did followed his instructions and typed in

> npm install --save redux react-redux.

in the command window. However, in my text editor I get these two error messages [(error message from ESlint)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daj0t.png).

I tried to google what dependencies are, and from what I understood they are modules that are required for the app to run. Regardless, I tried

> npm i -S react-redux

as well as reinstalling, but it did not work.([message from Command Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yfHY.png))

May somebody explain to me how I can solve these errors and what those messages in command center mean?

Comment: Does the ESLint error go away if you restart your server?  Also, adding the relevant error messages/code in your question is WAY better than linking to pictures of the code.  Please update your question.

Comment: No it doesn't. I added "import/no-extraneous-dependencies" : ["error", {"devDependencies": true}]
to make it go away.

Comment: Well, that's one way to "solve" your problem.  ESlint is pointing to something you probably should fix rather than ignore.  Can you please add to your question your package.json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\admin\package.json'

says that the project folder is not having "package.json" which will be available only in project's root folder

Please make sure you **do npm install in project's root folder**

Comment: I think that's where I messed up!

Answer (score 0):

I added "import/no-extraneous-dependencies" : ["error", {"devDependencies": true}] in my .eslintrc and it got rid of the error.